# Azure DevOps, Pipeline error ##[warning]Couldn't find a debug log in the cache or working directory JsNode

Tags: node.js, debugging, npm, devops, npm-build

I am trying to upload my JS app into Azure DevOps and during the running pipeline, I'm getting an error on the NPM build stage. ##[warning]Couldn't find a debug log in the cache or working directory. I believe this is the reason why NPM build is failing,
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Error: Npm failed with return code: 1
Did anyone have a similar problem? any clues?
Below are logs.

```
 ##[debug]findPath: 'C:\npm\cache\_logs'
 ##[debug]findOptions.allowBrokenSymbolicLinks: 'false'
 ##[debug]findOptions.followSpecifiedSymbolicLink: 'true'
 ##[debug]findOptions.followSymbolicLinks: 'true'
 ##[debug]  C:\npm\cache\_logs (directory)
 ##[debug]  C:\npm\cache\_logs\2022-06-09T09_03_45_496Z-debug-0.log (file)
 ##[debug]  C:\npm\cache\_logs\2022-06-09T09_03_46_269Z-debug-0.log (file)
 ##[debug]  C:\npm\cache\_logs\2022-06-09T09_03_47_005Z-debug-0.log (file)
 ##[debug]  C:\npm\cache\_logs\2022-06-09T09_03_47_757Z-debug-0.log (file)
 ##[debug]  C:\npm\cache\_logs\2022-06-09T09_03_48_499Z-debug-0.log (file)
 ##[debug]  C:\npm\cache\_logs\2022-06-09T09_03_49_272Z-debug-0.log (file)
 ##[debug]  C:\npm\cache\_logs\2022-06-09T09_03_50_016Z-debug-0.log (file)
 ##[debug]  C:\npm\cache\_logs\2022-06-09T09_03_50_833Z-debug-0.log (file)
 ##[debug]  C:\npm\cache\_logs\2022-06-09T09_03_51_628Z-debug-0.log (file)
 ##[debug]  C:\npm\cache\_logs\2022-06-09T09_03_52_416Z-debug-0.log (file)
 ##[debug]  C:\npm\cache\_logs\2022-06-09T09_03_53_188Z-debug-0.log (file)
 ##[debug]  C:\npm\cache\_logs\2022-06-09T09_03_54_118Z-debug-0.log (file)
 ##[debug]  C:\npm\cache\_logs\2022-06-09T09_03_55_141Z-debug-0.log (file)
 ##[debug]  C:\npm\cache\_logs\2022-06-09T09_03_55_976Z-debug-0.log (file)
 ##[debug]  C:\npm\cache\_logs\2022-06-09T09_03_56_789Z-debug-0.log (file)
 ##[debug]16 results
 ##[debug]found 16 paths
 ##[debug]applying include pattern
 ##[debug]adjustedPattern: 'C:\npm\cache\_logs\*-debug.log'
 ##[debug]0 matches
 ##[debug]0 final results
 ##[debug]Trying debug log location: D:\a\1\s\npm-debug.log
 ##[warning]Couldn't find a debug log in the cache or working directory**
 ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=warning;]Couldn't find a debug log in the cache or 
 working directory
 ##[debug]Agent.BuildDirectory=D:\a\1
 ##[debug]rm -rf D:\a\1\npm
 ##[debug]removing directory D:\a\1\npm
 ##[debug]task result: Failed
 ##[error]Error: Npm failed with return code: 1
 ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Error: Npm failed with return code: 1
 ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Error: Npm failed with return code: 1
 Finishing: npm build
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to delete package-lock.json file and re excute your pipeline

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I read previous answers on a similar topic and there was that suggestion, unfortunetly won't help with that case, it still has the same error message.